# rename file by joining two search results

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning python and also English, I am doing this code to read a TXT and find in it a sequence of numbers, then rename the file with the sequence found. But besides looking for this sequence of numbers, I needed to find some set of words, for example, if I find the words Apple, Watermelon and Pineapple, and not find Pumpkin, classifies TXT as "fruits", and when renaming the file renames with the sequence of digits plus an "f" of fruit for example:

```
name_files2 = os.listdir(path_txt)

for TXT in name_files2:
    with open(path_txt + '\\' + TXT, "r") as content:
        search = re.search(r'(\d{5})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{4})\.(\d)\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})|'
                           r'(\d{5})\s*\-\s*(\d{2})\s*\.\s*(\d{4})\.(\d)\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})|'
                           r'(\d{7})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{4})\.(\d)\.(\d{4})', content.read())
    if search is not None:
        name2 = search.group(0)
        name2 = re.sub(r"\D", "", name2)
        fp = os.path.join("18_digitos", name2 + "_%d.txt")
        postfix = 0
        while os.path.exists(fp % postfix):
            postfix += 1
        os.rename(
            os.path.join(path_txt, TXT),
            fp % postfix
        )
```

I can find the words in this way in the text, but I can not do both at the same time

```
if text_complete.find("apple") >= 0 and text_complete.find("watermelon") >= 0 and \
                text_complete.find("pineapple") >= 0 and text_complete.find("pumpkin") < 0:
    print("Find Fruit")
```

I need basically to make two codes work together, I need them to find the 18-digit sequence, identify the keywords and classify as fruits for example, and rename the file with the sequence found + key word ranking + increment. Example: 12345678901234567_f_0 , 12345678901234567_f_1.

Currently it only concatenates the sequence and increment, example: 12345678901234567_0 , 12345678901234567_1. The increment I made to differentiate the files when they have the same sequence of numbers

EDIT: what I am not getting is to join the sequence and classification fruit that were extracted from the same text. The same number, may have the classification fruits or vegetables, for example. So I need to find out which sequence came out each fruit or vegetable classification to rename the file

Comment: Sorry for my bad English, but I really need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to check the contents of the file twice: once to extract a sequence of numbers and once to check if it contains "fruit" words.

In order to look at the text more than once you should store the contents of the file in its own variable.

You can change the code in the `with` block to :

```
with open(path_txt + '\\' + TXT, "r") as content:
    text_complete = content.read()
```

And the later you can check for your number sequence

```
search = re.search(r'...', text_complete.read()) # ... is your long regular expression
```

And you can also run your `if` statement to check for "fruit" words:

```
if text_complete.find("apple") >= 0 and ... : # ... is the rest of your condition
    found_fruit = True
```

By storing the contents of the file as a string as the `text_complete` variable, you can refer to it multiple times, checking for something different each time.

Comment: Thanks... it has helped a lot, but what I am not getting is to join the sequence and classification fruit that were extracted from the same text. The same number, may have the classification fruits or vegetables, for example. So I need to find out which sequence came out each fruit or vegetable classification to rename the file

Comment: @stacker do you mean that you need to figure out how to add `'f'` or `'v'` to the file name?

Comment: exactly, this is the end result that I expect

Comment: @stacker ok, why not have a variable called something like `classification` to which you can assign either `'f'` if you found the fruit words and `'v'` if you found the vegetable words. For example, in the `if` statement in my example above, you would replace `found_fruit = True` with `classification = 'f'`. Then, when you are naming your file path you can add that variable: `fp = os.path.join("18_digitos", name2 + "_" + classification + "_%d.txt")`